Unable to Represent Micronaut Application Properties with Array of Object in AWS Parameter Store
How do I store a Micronaut application properties with array of object in AWS Parameter Store since we can't have square brackets in the parameter name of AWS Parameter Store?
Here's a snippet of properties that need to be stored in AWS Parameter Store,
micronaut:
  security:
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /hello
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /bye
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous()


I managed to solve this issue by decorating AWSParameterStoreConfigClient, bean that responsible to orchestrating the properties reading from AWS Parameter Store. Before implementing the solution please be aware that,

AWSParameterStoreConfigClient bean will still be loaded and perform the properties reading, including the API call to the cloud. Make sure that your app won't be disrupted by such behavior.
I chose to decorate the config-client instead of replace it because the constructor is protected by package-private access modifier. Also I wan't to avoid rewriting the whole implementation to make the solution is more future-proof and avoid wrong implementation.
This issue showing that AWS Parameter Store might not be the best solution to store your app configuration, considering its incompatibility to the common application configuration format. Even when you get creative maybe by storing the configuration as JSON in a single parameter, the stored configuration itself would be limited to the parameter size limitation.

Here's the solution code,
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.BootstrapContextCompatible
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requirements
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires
import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
import io.micronaut.context.env.MapPropertySource
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource
import io.micronaut.discovery.aws.parameterstore.AWSParameterStoreConfigClient
import io.micronaut.discovery.config.ConfigurationClient
import jakarta.inject.Singleton
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux

@Factory
@Requirements(
    Requires(env = ["ec2"]),
    Requires(beans = [AWSParameterStoreConfigClient::class])
)
@BootstrapContextCompatible
class ConfigurationClientConfiguration {
    @Singleton
    fun enhancedAWSParameterStoreConfigurationClient(
        delegate: AWSParameterStoreConfigClient,
    ) = object : ConfigurationClient {
        override fun getDescription() = "Decorated AWS Parameter Store"

        override fun getPropertySources(environment: Environment) = Flux.from(delegate.getPropertySources(environment))
            .map { propertySource ->
                var newPropertySource = (propertySource as MapPropertySource).asMap().toMutableMap()

                newPropertySource = newPropertySource.mapKeys { (key) ->
                    key.replace("\\.\\d+\\.".toRegex()) { matchResult ->
                        matchResult.value.replaceFirst(".", "[").replaceFirst(".", "].")
                    }
                }.toMutableMap()

                PropertySource.of(newPropertySource)
            }

    }
}


Did you read https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-aws-parameter-store-gradle-java.html before implementing this? This solution looks kind of hacky IMHO. BR

Yes @RoarS. I've read that doc and it's not showing on how to handle array-of-object configuration like micronaut.security.intercept-url-map. That's why I came up with this hack, inspired by this GitHub Micronaut issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-aws/issues/2145. As a mentioned in the answer, the problem itself might be the inability of AWS Parameter Store to fulfill standards application property format. The ultimate solution is to replace the AWS SSM with a better solution like Consul / Spring Config Server / K8s ConfigMap
